# htaccess redirect partial match url to another host

Tags: .htaccess

I have tried every suggestion I've found and still cannot get a partially matching url to redirect to another site. I have rogues who are adding strings such as '/hyperion-expert-in-san-angelo/' to the end of my domain in order to get server error log backlinks and I can't stop it and it is taking up a lot of bandwidth.

I can redirect each instance ok eg

```
Redirect 301 /hyperion-consultant-in-new-haven/ {new url}
Redirect 301 /lawson-developer-in-new-bedford/ {new url}
Redirect 301 /lawson-developer-in-new-orleans/ {new url}
Redirect 301 /oracle-developer-in-el-monte/ {new url}
Redirect 301 /hyperion-developer-in-san-angelo/ {new url}
Redirect 301 /lawson-expert-in-thousand-oaks/ {new url}
Redirect 301 /lawson-expert-in-flower-mound/ {new url}
Redirect 301 /hyperion-expert-in-san-diego/ {new url}
Redirect 301 /hyperion-developer-in-san-diego/ {new url}
Redirect 301 /oracle-expert-in-ellicott-city/ {new url}
```

but they keep coming. I want to redirect any url with hyperion, lawson etc to another site. This does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^hyperion(/|$) {new url} [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(hyperion|lawson|oracle).*$ {new url} [R=301,L,NC]
```

You don't need the `QSA` flag considering that these requests are just rogues.